# Image module (from PIL) not recognizing mode = "HSV"

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, hsv

I'm trying to take my HSV values and make an image out of it. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import colorsys

fp = open('pixels.txt', 'w')
fp2 = open('hsv.txt', 'w')
im = Image.open('colorimage.png')
imrgb = im.convert("RGB")
scale = 255.0

pixels = list(imrgb.getdata())
width, height = im.size
pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width] for i in xrange(height)]

for pixel in pixels:
        for x in pixel:
                print>>fp, x
                x = [x[0]/255,x[1]/255,x[2]/255]
                y = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(*x)
                w = [y[0]*360, y[1]*100, y[2]*100]
                h,s,v = [y[0]*360, y[1]*100, y[2]*100]
                print>>fp2, w

newimg = Image.new("HSV", im.size)

print "done"
```

The Image.new says it takes modes: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

But it doesn't read "HSV" as a mode. It says this as the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RGBtoHIS.py", line 25, in <module>
    newimg = Image.new("HSV", im.size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 1763, in new
    return Image()._new(core.fill(mode, size, color))
ValueError: unrecognized mode
```

Has anyone else had this issue with the Image module?

Other:
I would like to create a Hue image and a Saturation image. Is there a way to do this with the hue and saturation values I have?

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the Pillow docs, but you're not using Pillow -- you're using the original PIL version 1.1.7, as shown by your error message:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 1763, in new
```

and according to *its* documentation, it doesn't support HSV as a mode (see [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm#mode)).

Uninstall PIL, install Pillow, and then you should be able to do

```
In [12]: PIL.__version__
Out[12]: '3.4.2'

In [13]: Image.new("HSV", (100,100))
Out[13]: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=HSV size=100x100 at 0x7F4FA00F4F60>
```

Comment: I also installed PIL from a third party, how do I uninstall it?

Comment: sudo easy_install http://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz --- I used that command to install PIL because I couldn't get anything to work